# Creating triangle-like structure of lists in that hold numbers from bottom left

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a structure that would look like this, the number of items it could hold would be n:

```
7
4 8
2 5 9
1 3 6 10
```

And converting it to a list like so:

```
[[1, 3, 6, 10],[2, 5, 9],[4, 8],[7]]
```

I can't wrap my head around it, I figured each item increases by `1`, then `2` then `3` and so on, but the way I want them to store is something I can't figure out.

```
fn(6)

[[1 3 6],[2 5],[4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must be the most kind person ever, but it did seem like a fun thing to test out. Here is a function that works:

```
def fn(input):
    output = []

    # First row:
    row = [1]
    incrementor = 2
    while row[-1]+incrementor <= input:
        row.append(row[-1]+incrementor)
        incrementor += 1
    output.append(row)

    # Rest of rows:
    for i in range(len(output[0])-1):
        output.append([e-1 for e in output[-1][1:]])


print(fn(10))

>> [[1, 3, 6, 10], [2, 5, 9], [4, 8], [7]]
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed you are the kindest person ever. Could you elaborate a bit on the rest of the rows part?

Comment: So if you take a look at the final result, the above row is always the row under it, ignoring the first element and subracting 1 from each of the remainding element. The list comprehension I wrote appends a new row, based on the previous row, following the mentioned "criteria".